# use Ionic with intel XDK

Tags: ionic-framework, intel-xdk

I created a (HTML5 + Cordova) App using intel XDK. While creating project, I did not opt for "Use App designer".

I want to add ionic framework with it's all dependencies (angular etc.)

I didn't find any option to add ionic.

Comment: Hi, what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer. go to project page, you will find the following option:

[image]

Click on the "Add Bower Packages", you will the following screen:

[image]

Now search for ionic and add it. Now you are happy to go.